# iOS NSTimer firing twice

Tags: ios, nstimer

Hi  I'm trying to use NSTimer to create a countdown which and view this using a label. the problem is the label goes down in two's and i don't know why. any ideas?

heres my code

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       NSLog(@"%@", self.chosenTime);
       [self startGame];
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSString *timeString =  self.chosenTime;
       self.timer = [timeString intValue];
       self.countdown.text = timeString;
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)startGame
    {
        [self introCountdown];
        [self performSelector:@selector(goAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
        NSString *timeString =  self.chosenTime;
        self.timer = [timeString intValue];
        [self performSelector:@selector(startCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
    }

    - (void)startCountdown
    {
         //self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(decrementTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
         self.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(decrementTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    - (void)decrementTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
    {
       if(self.timer > 0)
       {
           self.timer = self.timer - 1;
           self.countdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.timer];
       }
       else 
       {
            [self.countdownTimer invalidate];
            self.countdownTimer = nil;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code where you call startCountDown ?

Comment: hmmm.. can you try calling the startCountDown explicitly ([self startCountdown]) and see if it works ?

Comment: BTW [super viewDidLoad] should be first to be executed in viewDidLoad()

Comment: You initialize self.timer twice: once in viewDidLoad and once in startGame.

Comment: @Jonas Byström Shouldn't be the problem

Comment: @Kai Nope, another bigger one. Unclean code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be correct. May be you are changing label's text from somewhere else?

Comment: i am changing it in view did unload to show the value and then want it to count down eery second from that value

Comment: Assume, you have `startValue = 10;`. And you want to label works smth like 10, 9, ..., 0. Well, you have to increment your value (`startValue = 11;` in this case), because the timer changes label's text AFTER the counter was decremented.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the misinterpretation, the code is correct, it seems a UI problem or handling label from somewhere else, attach your source with xib's if possible

Comment: that's not the answer to the question.

Comment: this doesn't work it counts down in two's still but it only does it once i want it so the label counts down every second

Comment: @Shahid Aslam You shouldn't edit your answer without keeping the original contents or marking new contents as "EDIT". That makes it impossible for later readers to follow the discussion.